# Using QWorkspace cascade

Tags: python, pyqt4, cascade

I'm trying to overload the QWorkspace class with my own cascade and tile definitions, but when I try to use the .move function, it moves the interior widget relative to the subwindow as opposed to moving the subwindow relative to the workspace.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
class MdiArea(QWorkspace):
    def tile(self):
        if len(self.windowList()) < 2:
            return

    def cascade(self):

        if len(self.windowList()) < 2:
            return

        windows = []
        for window in self.windowList():
            windows.append((window.width(), window.height(), window))

            windows.sort()
#        
            x = 0
            y = 0
            endX = self.width() - min(windows[-1][0], self.width())
            endY = self.height() - min(windows[-1][1], self.height())

        for i in range(len(windows)):

            x = i * 10
            y = i * 10

            width, height, window = windows[i]
            window.move(x, y)

            window.raise_()
```

Here is the code that finally worked for me (notice the 'parent()' addition in particular):
class MdiArea(QWorkspace):
    def tile(self):
        print self.width()
        if len(self.windowList()) < 2:
            return
        i=0
        for window in self.windowList():
            x = i * window.parent().width()
            y = 5
            window.parent().move(x, y)
            window.parent().raise_()
            i=i+1

```
def cascade(self):
    if len(self.windowList()) < 2:
        return
    i=0
    for window in self.windowList():
        x = i * 15
        y = i * 30            
        window.parent().move(x, y)
        window.parent().raise_()            
        i=i+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each window widget is put inside a frame widget, which is consequently the parent widget of that widget. So you need to move and raise `window.parentWidget()`

But the class `QWorkSpace` is deprecated and you should be using `QMdiArea` instead (whose `subWindowList` method actually returns the window list and not the internal widget list).

Comment: That is what I was missing.  I'm updating the program, so, ripping out all of the QWorkspace code and putting in QMdiArea is going to be too time consuming.